# argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r

I would like to replace the first 3 letters of txt.files with a sequence.

```
x <- list.files()
n <- seq(length(list.files()))
x2 <- gsub('^.{3}', n, x)
file.rename(x, x2)
```

the 4 files in the folder

```
2eEMORT.txt
3h4MORT.txt
4F1MORT.txt
841MORT.txt
```

were replaced by one file

```
1MORT.txt
```

Comment: What's `n`? What's `x`?

Comment: ```n``` is there ```x``` got lost, i added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the OP's code, `gsub` (or `sub`) is not vectorized for `replacement` - i.e. it takes a vector of length 1).  Hence, we get the warning message.  One option is to make use of `substring` (faster and efficient) along with `paste`

```
x2 <- paste0(seq_along(x), substring(x, 4))
x2
#[1] "1MORT.txt" "2MORT.txt" "3MORT.txt" "4MORT.txt"
```

---

Or with `paste` and `sub`.  Here, we match first 3 characters as in the OP's code and replace it with blank (`""`)  and then `paste`

```
x2 <- paste0(seq_along(x), sub("^.{3}", "", x))
```

---

Also, if we need to do this using regex, a vectorized option is `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)    
x2 <- str_replace(x, "^.{3}", as.character(n))
x2
#[1] "1MORT.txt" "2MORT.txt" "3MORT.txt" "4MORT.txt"
```

NOTE: None of the solutions use any loop

Now, we simply do

```
file.rename(x, x2)
```

#### data

```
x <- c("2eEMORT.txt", "3h4MORT.txt", "4F1MORT.txt", "841MORT.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the warning "argument 'replacement' has length >1 and only the first element will be used" is because you're supplying `n` -- a vector of the form `c(1, 2, ...)` -- as a string to replace the substring matching your regex `^.{3}`.

If what you want to do is replace the first three characters of each filename with a number you can sort by, here is one way to do it (comments explain each step):

```
# the files to be renamed 
fnames <- list.files()

# new prefixes to add: '001', '002', '003', etc. 
# (note usage of sprintf() to get left-padding for nice sorting) 
fname_prefixes <- sprintf("%03d", seq_along(fnames))

# sub the i-th prefix for the first three characters of the i-th filename 
new_fnames <- Map(function(fname, idx) gsub("^.{3}", idx, fname), 
                  fnames, fname_prefixes)
```

Then you can rename each file by iterating over the named list `new_fnames`:

```
for (idx in seq_along(new_fnames)){
  # can show a message so you can track what's going on  
  message('renaming ', names(new_fnames)[idx], ' to: ', new_fnames[[idx]])
  file.rename(from=names(new_fnames)[idx], to=new_fnames[[idx]])
}
```